# Bootstrap pull-up pull-down (aka vertical alignment) with buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a horizontal row of bootstrap buttons.
The buttons come in two sizes - medium and small.
I want the small buttons to stack vertically so that **2 small buttons occupy the same vertical space as one medium button**.
So here's a medium button:

```
      <a class="btn btn-lg top-buffer align-root half-width double-height btn-primary " id="WID020" href="#">&nbsp;
        <div id="EL034">
            <h6 class="align-bottom-left text-default ">MD. BTN</h6>
        </div>
        <div id="EL033">
            <i class="fa align-center-center fa-car fa-2x text-default"></i>
        </div>
      </a>
```

and here are two small buttons put into a `btn-group-vertical`:

```
     <div class="btn-group-vertical ">
        <div>
          <a class="btn btn-lg top-buffer align-root quarter-width btn-danger" style="vertical-align: top; display: table-cell;  " id="WID021" href="#">&nbsp;
            <div id="EL040"><i class="fa align-center-center fa-volume-up fa-6x text-default"></i></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a class="btn btn-lg top-buffer align-root quarter-width btn-warning" style="vertical-align:bottom; display: table-cell; position:relative;" id="WID021" href="#">&nbsp;
            <div id="EL040"><i class="fa align-center-center fa-volume-down fa-6x text-default"></i></div>
          </a>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Now the gotcha! I want the top button in this two button group, to align to the top and the bottom one to align to the bottom.

After much hacking around, I managed to get the top small button to move to vertically align at the top. I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but it seems to work:

`style="vertical-align: top; display: table-cell;"`

but the bottom button remains a stubborn challenge. Any ideas how to do this and stay in bootstrap/css land? Maybe the answer lies in a `flexbox`?

here's a bootply: [bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/ofeVQDEImB)

The issue is the orange button!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your demo, the spacing works fine, so this may be a browser issue; i'm using chrome v61.0.3163.79, for reference.

if that's not the issue, you might try moving away from the btn-group-vertical, as that might be overriding the separate alignments.

finally, if you're using Bootstrap 4(unfortunately, i'm not, so i can't verify this), [this may help you:](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/).  It seems they've added some vertical alignment classes in bootstrap 4 that may prove useful in these cases.